# Adding programmatically new route to zuul proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, routes, netflix-zuul

I am using a spring boot application with `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation. But I would like to add custom routes during runtime. How is this possible?

Existing documentation only shows static examples, in which routes are defined in the `application.yml`. Could you point me to code snippets of my use case.

In the `ZuulConfiguration` I found a possibility to add routes `routeLocator().getRoutes().add(route);` but they are not applied to the runtime. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot. Cheers

Gerardo

Comment: Hello @Gerardo, have you solved the problem already? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I did was subclass the `SimpleRouteLocator` class with my own `RouteLocator` class. Here is sample of what I did:

```
public class RouteLocator extends SimpleRouteLocator implements RefreshableRouteLocator {
    @Autowired
    private ZuulHandlerMapping zuulHandlerMapping;

    private Map<String, ZuulRoute> routes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public RouteLocator(TaskExecutor executor, String servletPath, ZuulProperties properties) {
        super(servletPath, properties);
        executor.execute(new ServiceWatcher());
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ZuulRoute> locateRoutes() {
        return this.routes;
    }

    @Override void refresh() {
        this.doRefresh();
    }

    private class ServiceWatcher implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            // Add your routes to this.routes here. 
            ZuulRoute route1 = new ZuulRoute("/somePath", "http://someResourceUrl:8080");
            ZuulRoute route2 = new ZuulRoute("/someOtherPath", "some-service-id");

            routes.put("/somePath", route1);
            routes.put("/someOtherPath", route2);

            zuulHandlerMapping.setDirty(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure when the `ServiceWatcher` gets called since in my actual code the `ServiceWatcher` wraps around a Kubernetes `Watcher` (since I am running Zuul in an OpenShift environment), but this should provide the gist of how to get started.